# 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am a final year student currently developing my Final Year Project and have run into an issue that I have so far been unable to figure out. I am trying to display rosters related to a list of Team ID's in the MyRosters view, but whenever I try to run the code I get an 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' error. Can  anybody help me with this please?

Below is the ActionResult:

```
    public ActionResult MyRosters()
    {
        string ClubName = Session["TeamName"].ToString();
        var teams = db.Teams.Where(x => x.TeamName.Contains(ClubName) || ClubName == null).ToList();
        int[] TeamID = new int[] { };
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Team t in teams)
        {
            TeamID[i] = t.TeamID;
            i++;
        }
        return View(db.Rosters.Where(x => x.TeamID.Equals(TeamID) || ClubName == null).ToList());
    }
```

And here is the MyRosters view:

```
    @model MunsterAdministrator.Models.Roster

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "MyRosters";
    }

    <h2>MyRosters</h2>

    <table class="table table-condensed">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Team.TeamName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fixture.FixtureID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player1)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player2)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player3)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player4)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player5)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player6)
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team.TeamName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fixture.FixtureID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player3)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player4)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player5)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player6)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player7)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player8)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player9)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player10)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player11)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player12)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player13)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player14)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player15)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player16)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player17)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player18)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.RosterID })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.RosterID })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RosterID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Any help you can give me would be hugely appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: check with a breakpoint if `TeamID[i] = t.TeamID;` is the line raising the exception

Answer (score 0):

your array has no element and you cant assign any value to its 0th element. use this

```
int[] TeamID = teams.Select(b=>b.TeamID).toArray();
```

instead this

```
int[] TeamID = new int[] { };
int i = 0;
foreach (Team t in teams)
{
    TeamID[i] = t.TeamID;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, seems to have removed the previous error. However, I am now getting the following as an error when trying to display the results in the view:     

Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Here is the line of code that the issue is arising from:
        
        return View(db.Rosters.Where(x => x.TeamID.Equals(TeamID.Equals(TeamID))|| ClubName == null).ToList());

Comment: you can't compare array of int with int, you should to use Contains() for array variables, please start a new question or edit this question to help others finding their solution ;-)